# accessibilityIncrement and accessibilityDecrement not called with a slider

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uislider

I'm trying to add accessibility to a simple `UISlider`. I read the [Apples adjustable document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitytraits/1620177-adjustable) and saw that I need to implement two functions from the `UIAccessibilityAction protocol`; `accessibilityIncrement()` and `accessibilityDecrement()`.

The problem I'm having is that even if I set the slider to be an accessibility element in `viewDidLoad` and setting `slider.accessibilityTraits = .adjustable`, the two override functions aren't called even if I change the values.

I also tried to set `slider.accessibilityLabel = "test"`, but it's still not reading the label. Only how far the slider has come. For instance "80%".

Any idea on how I can make this work? I also read these two posts on stackOverflow, but none of them worked for me. [accessibilityIncrement / Decrement not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462982/accessibilityincrement-decrement-not-called) and [Accessibility accessibilityDecrement() not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585236/accessibility-accessibilitydecrement-not-getting-called)

I can also mention that I also tried setting breakpoints at the `accessibilityIncrement()` and `accessibilityDecrement()`, but nothing happened.

#### My code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slider.isAccessibilityElement = true
    slider.accessibilityLabel = "test"
    slider.accessibilityTraits = .adjustable
    
}


override func accessibilityIncrement() {
    slider.accessibilityValue = textField.text!
}

override func accessibilityDecrement() {
    slider.accessibilityValue = textField.text!
}


@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    guard let unit = question?.unit else { return }
    
    let currentValue = Int(sender.value + 0.5)
    textField.text = "\(currentValue) \(unit)"
    
    
    slider.accessibilityLabel = textField.text!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implement the `accessibilityIncrement()` and `accessibilityDecrement()` methods in your view controller but they **should belong to the created slider** whose trait should be `.adjustable`.

I suggest you take a look at this [accessibility site](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#continuous-adjustable-values) where a complete example about adjustable values with code snippets and illustrations is provided for both ObjC and Swift.

Following this example will allow to **call the `accessibilityIncrement()` and `accessibilityDecrement()` methods with your slider**.